# rowwise maximum for R

Tags: r, max

I have a dataframe as below. I want to get a column of maximums for each row. But that column should ignore value 9 if it is present in that row.
How can i achive that efficiently?

```
df <- data.frame(age=c(5,6,9), marks=c(1,2,7), story=c(2,9,1))
df$max <- apply(df, 1, max)    
df
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
df$colMax <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x[x != 9]))
```

Comment: Well, it does create extra copies. You could wrap the other answers in functions to hide that a copy is created.

Comment: @Roland ok, corrected. (I meant you don't end up with another data.frame and you don't need to define an extra function which removes it)

Comment: **Side Note:** Using `vapply` offers significant boost especially for large DFs (i.e. `vapply(df, function(x) max(x[x != 9]), numeric(1))`)

Answer (score 22):

The `pmax` function would be useful here. The only catch is that it takes a bunch of vectors as parameters. You can convert a data.frame to parameters with `do.call`. I also set the 9 values to NA as suggested by other but do so using the somewhat unconventional `is.na<-` command.

```
do.call(pmax, c(`is.na<-`(df, df==9), na.rm=T))
# [1] 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Substitute `9` with `NA` and then use `pmax` as suggested by @MrFlick in his deleted answer:

```
df2 <- df #copy df because we are going to change it
df2[df2==9] <- NA
do.call(function(...) pmax(..., na.rm=TRUE), df2)
#[1] 5 6 7
```

Comment: #or do.call(`pmax`, c(df2, na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] 5 6 7

Comment: Why should we prefer pmax over max?

Comment: @rpierce I didn't say that, did I? These functions do different things.

Comment: You didn't. They just both seem to being used for the same purpose here and I'm not a math guy who can interpret the help file to tell the difference nor am I a trained programmer who can intuit which function is more efficient. Thus, I asked.

Comment: `do.call(pmax, DF)` gives the same result as `apply(DF, 1, max)` (provided `DF` is a data.frame with all numeric columns), but is faster by a factor of 100 on a data.frame with 2 columns and 1e4 rows. If you don't understand the documentation look at the examples section and play around with the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
#make a copy of your data.frame
tmp.df <- df
#replace the 9s with NA
tmp.df[tmp.df==9] <- NA
#Use apply to process the data one row at a time through the max function, removing NA values first
apply(tmp.df,1,max,na.rm=TRUE)
```