# Apply Function Across Columns in data.table with do.call and .SD in R

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, do.call

I'm trying to create a variant of `pmax` / `pmin` that works with an additional `filter_value` parameter across an arbitrary set of columns that would be defined using `.SD` / `.SDcols`.  The first version of the function below hard-codes the filter value, but works with `.SD`:

```
testFuncV1 <- function(...) { 
  cols <- list(...)
  num_cols <- length(cols)
  num_records <- length(cols[[1]])
  max_records <- c()
  for (record_num in 1:num_records) {
    v <- c()
    for (l in cols) {
      v <- c(v, l[[record_num]])
    }
    filt_v <- Filter(function(x) { x <= 1 }, v)
    if (length(filt_v) == 0) {
      max_records <- c(max_records, NA) 
    } else {
      max_records <- c(max_records, max(filt_v))
    }
  }
  max_records
}

test_dt_v1 <- data.table(a = c(1,3,5), b = c(2,3,-1), c = c(-3, 5, 2))

test_dt_v1[, max_with_filter := do.call(testFuncV1, .SD), .SDcols = c('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

returns:

```
   a  b  c max_with_filter
1: 1  2 -3               1
2: 3  3  5              NA
3: 5 -1  2              -1
```

The second version of the function below takes a second `filter` parameter, but I was not able to get it to work with `.SD`, and rather, had to pass the individual column vectors in as a list to get things to work:

```
testFuncV2 <- function(cols, filter) { 
  num_cols <- length(cols)
  num_records <- length(cols[[1]])
  max_records <- c()
  for (record_num in 1:num_records) {
    v <- c()
    for (l in cols) {
      v <- c(v, l[[record_num]])
    }
    filt_v <- Filter(function(x) { x <= filter }, v)
    if (length(filt_v) == 0) {
      max_records <- c(max_records, NA) 
    } else {
      max_records <- c(max_records, max(filt_v))
    }
  }
  max_records
}

test_dt_v2 <- data.table(a = c(1,3,5), b = c(2,3,-1), c = c(-3, 5, 2))

test_dt_v2[, max_with_filter := do.call(testFuncV2, list(list(test_dt_v2$a, test_dt_v2$b, test_dt_v2$c), 1))]
```

also returns:

```
   a  b  c max_with_filter
1: 1  2 -3               1
2: 3  3  5              NA
3: 5 -1  2              -1
```

Ideally, I'd be able to either figure out an approach that works with `.SD` using `do.call`, or substitute in something that works with `lapply` (which I also experimented around with, to no avail).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Building it analogous to pmin/pmax is an interesting idea, but it would be easier to tackle if you store your data in long form. So if you had `DT = melt(test_dt_v1[, row := .I], id = "row")`, then it would just be `DT[value <= 1][.(unique(DT$row)), on=.(row), max(value), by=.EACHI]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `apply(MARGIN=1, ...)`

```
func <- function(x, threshold) {
    if (any(x <= threshold)) return(max(x[x <= threshold])) 
    NA
}
test_dt_v1[, max_with_filter := apply(.SD, 1, func, threshold=1),
    .SDcols=c("a","b","c")]
```

Another option using `do.call` and `pmax` by converting values above 1 to NA first (idea came from [rowwise maximum for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497186/rowwise-maximum-for-r/24497217#24497217))

```
test_dt_v1[, max_with_filter := do.call(pmax, c(`is.na<-`(.SD, .SD>1), na.rm=T))]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I've been experimenting with this further and gotten to a point where I'm able to find the filtered value as expected, but want to take this one step further and am having trouble.  Essentially, I want to not only find the value, but the column name of said value (the data has pairs of dates and values - I want to get the date field suffix and find the value).  I've got `which.min(as.numeric(as.Date(date_cols[!is.na(date_cols) & date_cols > as_of_date], "%Y-%m-%d")))` to get the index, but then I'm not sure how to get the column name.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've tried to access the colname by `colnames(date_cols)["index from above"]`, but it's unclear to me exactly what data type `date_cols` is in this context.

Comment: maybe you want to post another question? its hard to understand what you need in a comment

Comment: I was able to solve this second part.  Thank you for the help!