# r - filtering alphanumeric factor columns by numeric values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very messy data frame consisting of factor columns with numbers and characters. I need to filter the rows with numeric values above a threshold. However, this is a problem because my columns are factors that cannot be turned to numeric, due to the presence of characters in them.

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c("Egg", "", "3"),
  Col2 = c("", "Flour", ""),
  Col3 = c("2", "", "Bread"),
  Col4 = c("4", "", ""),
  Col5 = c("", "6", "8")
)
```

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
> DF
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
1  Egg           2    4     
2      Flour               6
3    3       Bread         8
```

Where each column is a factor:

```
> class(DF$Col1)
[1] "factor"
>
```

In this example, how do I filter rows with numeric values above, say, 5 in at least one column? The desired output in this example, looks like this:

```
> DF
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
2      Flour               6
3    3       Bread         8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get some warnings from `dplyr` but this works as well:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(if_else(is.na(as.numeric(.)), FALSE, as.numeric(.) > 5)))

  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
1      Flour               6
2    3       Bread         8
```

Per @Frank's suggestion (a bit cleaner than above):

```
DF %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(as.numeric(as.character(.)) > 5))

  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
1      Flour               6
2    3       Bread         8
```

Comment: Or, if the OP for some reason wants them kept as factors: `DF %>% filter_all(any_vars(as.numeric(as.character(.)) > 5))` -- it seems filter will skip rows for which any_vars returns NA.

Answer (score 3):

One can pick out only `numeric` values using `gsub` from each observation and convert it to numeric. Afterwards, in base-R `subset` with `apply` can provide a solution as:

```
subset(DF, apply(DF, 1, function(x){
                #Get only numeric values and convert to numeric
                val <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "",x))
                any(val[!is.na(val)] > 5)
                 })
       )

#   Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
# 2      Flour               6
# 3    3       Bread         8
```

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is:

```
DF[do.call(function(...) pmax(..., na.rm=TRUE), data.frame(lapply(lapply(DF, as.character), as.numeric), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) > 5,]
```

To explain what this is doing, the `lapply(DF, as.character)` is removing the factors, then `lapply(lapply(DF, as.character), as.numeric)` is converting the characters to numbers (the text becomes NA), and then `data.frame(lapply(lapply(DF, as.character), as.numeric), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` changes it back to a dataframe, e.g.

```
> data.frame(lapply(lapply(DF, as.character), as.numeric), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1   NA   NA    2    4   NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA    6
3    3   NA   NA   NA    8
```

The do.call with pmax finds the row maximum (thanks [rowwise maximum for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497186/rowwise-maximum-for-r)) and then we can easily filter for a maximum value above 5.